# Why string can concate with wchar_t?

Tags: c++, string, wchar-t

Why can we directly concatenate a string with a wchar_t?

```
int main()
{
    std::string fileName = "test";
    fileName += L'\\';
    std::cout << fileName << "\n";
}
```

I can compile and run successly.

Comment: Implicit conversions, it can hop from wchar_t through int to char.

Comment: It would not run successfully if the wide char were not in the ASCII range.

Comment: @acraig5075 _implicit overflow in conversion_

Comment: Do don't concatenate the string with the `wchar_t`. You call a method the appends a character to the `std::string` object.